# is the sequence of non-negative integers a limiting sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

consider the sequence of all non-negative integers

\begin{align}
&
0, 1, 2, 3... \\
&a_0 = 0 \\
&a_1= 1\\
&a_2 =2 \\
\end{align}

http://oeis.org/A001477

If we denote by $S(t)$ the sequence a_0=0,a_1=1, a_2=2, ..., a_t=t, and if we want to analyze $S(\infty)=(0,1,2,3,\ldots)$, can we say that we are analyzing the limiting sequence $S(\infty)$?   Is the word "limit" correctly employed here? If so, what would be a good reference to point? If not, what would be the best word to use?

Comment: Better would be "a series diverging to $\infty$". A "limited sequence" is expected to have a (finite) limit.

Comment: I am amazed that you are linking to a page of particular sequences to "help" represent the sequence of nonnegative integers listed in order.  I also do not know what is meant by $S(t)$: is it the set of integers $\{1, 2, ..., t\}$? It has only a finite number of values, do you really want to call it a "sequence"?  Is it a "sequence" or just a "set"? What is $S(\infty)$? If $S(t)$ is the set $\{1, 2, ..., t\}$ then $$ \mathbb{N} = \{1, 2, 3, ...\} = \cup_{t=1}^{\infty} S(t)$$

Comment: I don't know if I'm more surprised that the non-negative integers are in OEIS or there are 1476 sequences that were listed before it....

Comment: S(infinity) is the sequence, not a set. let me fix the notation in the question

Comment: I don't know if I'm more surprised that the non-negative integers are in OEIS or there are 1476 sequences that were listed before it.... --- :) that is funny indeed :)